# ORM golang Relation with where clause

Tags: database, go, orm

I am stuck trying to make a query using the golang orm. What I want to do is get all Messages with Name x or y, in the Request with RequestID = request_id, but I want too to get the Requests with Method = z even the related messages name are not name_x or name_y. An example about what I want to get is, having this database:

```
request
    id  method  created_at
    0   z       xxx
    1   z       xxx
    2   m       xxx
    3   m       xxx

trace
    id  request_id  created_at
    0   0           xxx
    1   1           xxx
    2   2           xxx
    3   2           xxx
    4   3           xxx
    
message
    id  trace_id    name    more_info
    0   0           n       name_n_0_method_z_0
    1   0           x       name_x_1_method_z_0
    2   2           x       name_x_2_method_m_2
    3   2           n       name_n_3_method_m_2
    4   3           y       name_y_4_method_m_3
```

So after my query, the messages I should have are:
name_n_0_method_z_0 (method is z)
name_x_1_method_z_0 (name is x and method is z)
name_x_2_method_m_2 (name is x)
name_y_4_method_m_3 (name is y)

and the not selected entries in this case is only one:
name_n_3_method_m_2 (the name is not x or y, and the method is not z)

What I am doing is:

```
type Request struct {
    ID             int64
    Method         string
    RequestID      string
    Traces         []Trace
    CreatedAt      time.Time `sql:",null"`
}
type Trace struct {
    ID        int64
    RequestID int64
    Messages  []*Message
    CreatedAt time.Time `sql:",null"`
}
type Message struct {
    ID        int64     `sql:"id"`
    TraceID   int64     `sql:"trace_id"`
    Name      string    `sql:"name"`
    MoreInfo string
}

func GetMessagesByNamesAndMethod(names []string, method, requestID string) {

    query := db.Model(&requests).
        Where("request.request_id = ?", requestID).
        Order("created_at ASC")
    query.
        Relation("Traces", func(q *orm.Query) (*orm.Query, error) {
        return q, nil
    }).
        Relation("Traces.Messages", func(q *orm.Query) (*orm.Query, error) {
            // 1-> q.Where("name in (?) OR request.method = ?", pg.In(names),
            q.Where("name in (?)", pg.In(names)) method) // <- 1.b
            return q.OrderExpr("message.created_at ASC"), nil
    })
    // 2-> query.WhereOr("request.method = ?", method)
}
```

The commented lines are the last attempts I tried:
1 -> In this case I remove the line 1.b. Doing this, I get an error.
2 -> There is no error in the execution, but I am not able to get the method = z entries

I hope to be clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you cross check what sql query is exactly getting created by using `github.com/go-pg/pg/extra/pgdebug`. Correct me if i am wrong are you using this library : `https://github.com/go-pg/pg` and also specify the error here.

Comment: Hi @gopher88 yes exactly I am using this library. Ok!! I will try with the debugger. Thanks.